# Adding all the Matrix Block field types of the same kind to get a total

Tags: templating, matrix, math

I have a Matrix block with a description field and a number field for hours. Let's say while creating an entry I add in 3 of these blocks with each having a different amount for the hours.

How can I add each of those 3 amounts and get a total amount?

I've spent quite a while researching and can't figure out what kind of syntax would make this work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twig allows you to add variables just as they were integers. You'll want to setup your `totalHours` variable before your loop begins so that the `totalHours` variable is available in the scope outside of the loop itself.

Something like this should work for you:

```
{# Create a variable to track your total hours #}
{% set totalHours = 0 %}

{% for block in entry.matrixFieldHandle %}

    {% if block.type == 'hoursBlock' %}
        {# Increment your total hours by adding the value
           of your hours block to the current totalHours #}
        {% set totalHours = totalHours + block.hoursFieldHandle %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

{# Output the result #}
Total Hours: {{ totalHours }}
```

While I can't test your specific code, here's a generic example that is doing the same thing that will work if you copy and paste it to your template:

```
{% set totalHours = 0 %}

{% for hours in 0..3 %}
    {% set totalHours = totalHours + hours %}
{% endfor %}

Total Hours: {{ totalHours }}
```

Comment: Perfect - It never occurred to me to set the variable initially blank and then iterate over it. Still new to this craft thing :) Thanks!